# Adding legend by list within subplot Matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I want to plot 2 different graphs in one plot. One graph is just one line, so no problem with labeling the legend. In df_2_plot is a list of tickers that is delivered, so more lines and more tickers within legend. If I label them like this, I only receive the list several times in the legend, instead of the right ticker for each line.

I tried to work with for loops but can't find a solution.

```py
def func_plot_DataFrame(df_2_plot, legend_lst):
    
    
    y1 = df_2_plot
    y2 = df_infektionsgeschehen

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    
    ax1.plot(y1, label = legend_lst)
    ax2.plot(y2, 'grey', linewidth=2, alpha=0.3, label = 'Neuinfektionen')


    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: All you need is `ax = df_infektionsgeschehen.plot(figsize=(8, 6))` and then `df_2_plot.plot(color='gray', alpha=0.3, ax=ax, secondary_y=True)`. Use `y=legend_list` in the first plot only if there are more than the 3 columns in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ax1.legend` instead of using the `label` argument directly in `ax1.plot`

```py
ax1.legend(labels=legend_lst)
```

Have a look at the official documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)